# extract the <strong> tag values using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the values of strong and sup tag from the below html code:

```
[<li class="price-current"><span class="price-current-label"></span>$<strong>299</strong><sup>.99</sup> <a class="price-current-num" href="https://www.newegg.com/xfx-radeon-rx-5600-xt-rx-56xt6df46/p/N82E16814150835?Item=N82E16814150835&amp;buyingoptions=New">(4 Offers)</a><span class="price-current-range"><abbr title="to">–</abbr></span></li>]
```

[image]

Comment: can you please add the html code?

Comment: Along with html code include even the code snippet your using for scrapping.

Comment: Please don't put a picture of code or data or desired output. Copy paste the code and data and output from the site / software you are using and paste it here. Then select those code areas or data areas or output areas and press the `{}` code formatting option to format it accordingly. okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
output = []
for soup in data3:
    output.append(soup.find("strong"))
    output.append(soup.find("sup"))
```

After running this, `output` list has the first `strong` and `sup` elements from all elements of `data3`.

If you want the text inside the tags, you can use `.content` or `.get_text()` after the `find` calls. Like `soup.find("strong").get_text()`.

See https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find for more help about Beautiful Soup.

Comment: Thanks @piii_ke I was able to get the output as : [<strong>299</strong>, <sup>.99</sup>] , I want only 299 and .99 as my output .I did try output[0] but its returning the tags along with the value.would be great if you could help me with this.

Comment: @Sushmita098 I have updated the answer to address that.

Answer (score 0):

```
soup3=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
spans=soup3.findAll('strong')
spans=soup3.findAll('sup')
```